# issue with "@id" vs "@+id" in positioning in Relative Layout

Tags: android

Good day, i have a slight issue with relative layouts and i don't know why. Normally when you trying to position relative to other views, you use "@id" but it doesn't seem to position at all. only when i use the value "@+id" would it go correctly. in the example below, i have 4 views in a horizontal orientation i want the TextView with "percentage_id" to be positioned in between the imageviews but closer to the last one.

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/sales_id"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:text="£0.00"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:textColor="#AADDEE"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" >
    </TextView>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/arrow_id"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/sales_id"
        android:baselineAlignBottom="true"
        android:src="@drawable/rightarrow" >
    </ImageView>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/percentage_id"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/imagearrow_id"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/arrow_id"
        android:text="0.00%"
        android:textColor="#606090"
        android:textSize="18sp" >
    </TextView>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imagearrow_id"
        android:layout_width="20dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
        android:layout_weight="0"
        android:gravity="right"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:src="@drawable/rightarrow" >
    </ImageView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Now no matter what i do, it just goes to the default position in the relative layout and only when i use "@+id" instead of "@id" does it go to the correct position. I know sometimes it can give error if the view am trying to reference has not been declared yet but even if i place the textview last, i still can't get it where i want until i use "@+id".

is this is a new thing that works also with Relative Layout? because i have no idea why its not working with "@id". am i fine this way? anyone encountered the same issue? see some tutorials on the net use "@+id" for positioning too. Thank you

Comment: The code you showed, is it a variant that is working OK or not?

Comment: @Nick  yeah its working as long as i make this line in the textview  android:layout_toRightOf="@id/arrow_id" which is strange.

Comment: Use the + when declaring a view; skip it when referencing one. Since the `imagearrow_id` one is not yet declared, you can't reference it form the TextView. Try putting the TextView declaration after the ImageView with `imagearrow_id`.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Although you *can* refer to views declared later in the hierarchy, the XML document is still parsed sequentially. The first time that you refer to a particular ID, you *have* to prefix it with `@+id`. In actuality, you can prefix every reference to an ID with `@+id` and everything will work -- in fact, this is what happens if you design your interface with the graphical editor. Just to be safe, everything is prefixed with `@+id`. The `+` simply tells it to generate an ID in `R.java` if and only if it has not already been defined. If you try to define it more than once, it just sees that it's already been defined and continues on normally.

In your XML, you reference `imagearrow_id` from your `percentage_id` TextView. However, at this point the `imagearrow_id` has not yet been defined. For this scenario, you could simply prefix the `layout_toLeftOf=@+id/imagearrow_id` in your TextView, and then below, when defining your ImageView (`imagearrow_id`), you would *not* need the `+` in the `android:id` attribute.

Comment: @kcoppock Do you have a reference about this sentence "If you try to define it more than once, it just sees that it's already been defined and continues on normally."

Answer (score 3):

`@+id` is used when declaring the ID for the first time, and you should not use it in the positioning of elements. It should be used only for the `android:id` attribute.

`@id` on the other hand is used to reference an existing ID.

In a `RelativeLayout`, you cannot reference views below the referencing view in the current code. So if you have the following layout:

```
LayoutRoot
    View1
    View2
    View3
```

View1 cannot, or rather should not, use View2 and View3 to define its position. View2 should use only View1 to define its position, and View3 can use both View1 and View2.

Essentially, you can use `@id` whenever the view you're referencing through it has been declared above the referencing view in the layout file.

So simply switching the code blocks' position of your last two widgets should allow you to use `@id`:

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/sales_id"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:text="£0.00"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:textColor="#AADDEE"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" >
    </TextView>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/arrow_id"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/sales_id"
        android:baselineAlignBottom="true"
        android:src="@drawable/rightarrow" >
    </ImageView>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imagearrow_id"
        android:layout_width="20dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
        android:layout_weight="0"
        android:gravity="right"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:src="@drawable/rightarrow" >
    </ImageView>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/percentage_id"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/imagearrow_id"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/arrow_id"
        android:text="0.00%"
        android:textColor="#606090"
        android:textSize="18sp" >
    </TextView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Not entirely true. `@+id` is used when declaring the ID for the first time, but you absolutely *must* use it for positioning elements, if the element that you are referencing has not yet been defined. For example, `percentage_id` references `imagearrow_id`, but `imagearrow_id` is defined below `percentage_id`. In this case, the reference to `imagearrow_id` in the `percentage_id` TextView should be prefixed using `@+id`.

Comment: I know. I'm saying you *shouldn't* be using an as-of-yet undeclared element to define positioning in the first place. If the element isn't declared, and you absolutely cannot declare it before the referencing view, then you should use @+id. Personally though, believe that you should declare the elements before referencing them.

Comment: There are situations where you can't, though. For instance, if the Z-order of the child views is important, you would have to define them out of order.

Comment: I realize that. I said in my comment "If the element isn't declared, and you absolutely cannot declare it before the referencing view, then you should use @+id" :-)

Comment: @RaghavSood,  Thanks a lot!! sorry, can only accept one answer.

Comment: No problem. @kcoppock's answer is better, so I can live with it.

Comment: Though this an old thread, regarding the statement "It should be used only for the android:id attribute.". The @+android:id will create the id in android namespace which we may not want. Instead @+id will suffice and should be used whenever we first declare the element. For all future references, @id should be used

Answer (score 0):

After experimenting with ConstraintLayout, check the snippet of code below, **both views are wrapped in constraintLayout**, i'll just paste the case code:

```
<android.support.v4.widget.ContentLoadingProgressBar
            android:id="@+id/progress"
            android:layout_width="150dp"
            android:layout_height="150dp"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.3"
            style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleLarge"
            android:visibility="@{safeUnbox(viewmodel.isLoading) ? View.VISIBLE : View.INVISIBLE}"
            />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/click_load"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:text="@{viewmodel.text}"
            android:textSize="22sp"
            android:visibility="@{safeUnbox(viewmodel.isLoading) ? View.INVISIBLE : View.VISIBLE}"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/progress"
            tools:text="ojoooihoihohoihiohhoihio" />
```

the line:

```
 app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/progress"
```

displays the textview pinned to the top of the view window in the editor, everything look fine in runtime but still this was confusing, now if you write it this way

```
 app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/progress"
```

displays textview below the progress in UI editor as expected, reading through kcoppock explanation i find it matching the case.