# Xamarin - Visual Studio 2013: Widgets overlapping in Relative view

Tags: android, android-layout, visual-studio-2013, xamarin, android-relativelayout

Using Xamarin 3.9.236 and Visual Studio 2013, I have a VERY basic project to test a layout.  My Layout source is as follows...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <Button
        android:text="Prev"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/buttonPrev"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" />
    <Button
        android:text="Next"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/buttonNext"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true" />
    <ImageView
        android:src="@drawable/Untitled1"
        android:layout_width="160dp"
        android:layout_height="160dp"
        android:id="@+id/imageCourse"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp" />
    <TextView
        android:text="Small Text"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/textTitle"
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp" />
    <TextView
        android:text="Medium Text"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:id="@+id/textTitle"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/imageCourse"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

But the output is not as expected.  I am doing this through a PluralSight Course, but they are using a MUCH older version of Xamarin, and don't seem to be having this issue.

Please see the following image for what I am trying to do...[image: Relative Layout Issue, widget.TextView is being overlapped by widget.ImageView]

As you can see, the widget.TextView is being overlapped by widget.ImageView

Answer (score 0):

Try swapping the order of the TextViews in the layout. Sometimes they need to be ordered correctly so it recognises the ID of the view it is supposed to be below.

Comment: Yes, this is correct. He is referencing the textTitle textview in the textView1 textview by using `android:layout_below="@id/textTitle"`. You must use "@+id" (notice the plus sign because it hasn't been defined yet. The Xml is parsed sequentially.) See this [post](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12805306/1296369) for details.