# Tried the solution but didnt worked error: Error parsing XML: not well-formed (invalid token)

Tags: android, xml

I have tried everything but unable to resolve this error in my XML file while working in Android. Also whenever I assign ids my R file is not tracing the id's. It always shows R cannot be resolved or is not a field and the id's which I am using is also saying the same.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="#d6f5FF">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <Button 
            android:id="v1"
            android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
            android:layout_width="120dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
            android:layout_marginLeft="90dip"
            android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
            android:text="e"
            android:background="@drawable/round_button" />

        <Button 
            android:id="v2"
            android:layout_width="120dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
            android:layout_marginLeft="90dip"
            android:text="d"
            android:background="@drawable/round_button" />

        <Button 
            android:id="v3"
            android:layout_width="120dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
            android:layout_marginLeft="90dip"
            android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
            android:text="c"
            android:background="@drawable/round_button" />

        <Button 
            android:id="v4"
            android:layout_width="120dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
            android:layout_marginLeft="90dip"
            android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
            android:text="b"        
            android:background="@drawable/round_button" />

        <Button 
            android:id="v5"
            android:layout_width="120dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
            android:layout_marginLeft="90dip"
            android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
            android:text="a"
            android:background="@drawable/round_button" />

    </LinearLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

Comment: Is the very last `>` a copy-paste issue or do you really  have TWO of them in your code?

Comment: Ya i have two of them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to specify `@+id/` for each id.  See [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12805091/issue-with-id-vs-id-in-positioning-in-relative-layout/12805306#12805306) for a good explanation.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
 android:background="#d6f5FF"  >

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <Button 
        android:id="@+id/v1"
        android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
        android:layout_width="120dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
        android:layout_marginLeft="90dip"
        android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
        android:text="e"
        android:background="@drawable/round_button"/>
    <Button 
        android:id="@+id/v2"
        android:layout_width="120dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
        android:layout_marginLeft="90dip"
        android:text="d"
        android:background="@drawable/round_button"    
        />
    <Button 
        android:id="@+id/v3"
        android:layout_width="120dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
        android:layout_marginLeft="90dip"
        android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
        android:text="c"
        android:background="@drawable/round_button"
        />
    <Button 
        android:id="@+id/v4"
        android:layout_width="120dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
        android:layout_marginLeft="90dip"
        android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
        android:text="b"        
        android:background="@drawable/round_button"/>               
    <Button 
        android:id="@+id/v5"
        android:layout_width="120dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
        android:layout_marginLeft="90dip"
        android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
        android:text="a"
        android:background="@drawable/round_button"/>

    </LinearLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two close signs in the last tag

```
</LinearLayout>>
```