# [Android][XML]Error:(19, 31) No resource found that matches the given name.(layout_above)

Tags: android, xml

here is my xml file and I don't know why

```
android:layout_above="@id/PairNow"
```

will cause my build fail.

Please help to resolve this problem, thanks!

Xml::

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="com.example.mybt.MainActivity">

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Paired Device!"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:id="@+id/PairTitle"/>
<ListView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/list_devices"
    android:layout_below="@id/PairTitle"
    android:layout_above="@id/PairNow"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" ></ListView>
<Button
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:id="@+id/PairNow"
    android:text="Pair Now"
    android:textSize="30dp"/>
```

Error message:

```
Error:(19, 31) No resource found that matches the given name (at 'layout_above' with value '@id/PairNow').
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Either declare your `Button` before `ListView`, or use `+` while giving reference in `ListView`.

```
android:layout_above="@+id/PairNow"
```

**UPDATE**

you might raise question that what is problem with your code, it's defenitely correct, but XML document is parced sequentially. So when you are giving reference to `Button` in your `ListView`, Button is not create at that time. Check [this reference](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12805306/3134215) for more.

Comment: Thanks, but one more question... what is the difference between the listView tag like:<ListView ...</ListView>   and  <ListView  ... />

Comment: There is no difference between them.

Comment: @himaChen yes there is no deference, you can take reference of HTML tags, XML tags are just like that only

Answer (score 2):

When you provide a reference of the layouts below the current widget you should use @+id/anyidTitle for that so change your code to following

Wrong

```
@id/PairNow
```

Corrent

```
@+id/PairNow
```

Answer (score 0):

Just change

```
@id/PairNow
```

to

```
@+id/PairNow
```

Because id PairNow doesn't exist before the Button with id PairNow.You can always use @+id/ instead of @id/.