# Using @id instead @+id in android layout button orientation goes wrong

Tags: android, android-layout, android-xml

> EDIT: Restarting android studio resolved the problem. I guess code wise there was no issue.

I am new to android. I was learning relative layout and making design of a calculator. As per my understanding `@+id` is to create new and `@id` to refer the already existing id.
If you refer the xml below it works fine and I am getting all the buttons with proper alignment but whenever I remove the + symbol from  `android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/two"` or any other place where I am using the id to refer the original id, all alignment goes weird.

Not Working image eg.: removed the + sign from the statement `android:layout_below="@+id/calculation"`

[image: remove the + sign from the statement android:layout_below="@+id/calculation"]

My xml source looks like this.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/calculation"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:padding="100dp"
        android:text="" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/one"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="6dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/calculation"
        android:onClick="appendOne"
        android:text="1" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/two"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="6dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/calculation"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/one"
        android:onClick="appendTwo"
        android:text="2" />
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/three"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="6dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/calculation"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/two"
        android:onClick="appendThree"
        android:text="3" />
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/plus"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="6dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/calculation"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/three"
        android:onClick="plusOperation"
        android:text="+" />
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/four"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="6dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/three"
        android:onClick="appendFour"
        android:text="4" />
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/five"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="6dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/two"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/four"
        android:onClick="appendFive"
        android:text="5" />
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/six"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="6dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/three"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/five"
        android:onClick="appendSix"
        android:text="6" />
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/minus"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="6dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/plus"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/six"
        android:onClick="minusOperation"
        android:text="-" />
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/seven"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="6dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/four"
        android:onClick="appendSeven"
        android:text="7" />
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/eight"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="6dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/five"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/seven"
        android:onClick="appendEight"
        android:text="8" />
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/nine"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="6dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/six"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/eight"
        android:onClick="appendNine"
        android:text="9" />
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/mul"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="6dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/minus"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/nine"
        android:onClick="mulOperation"
        android:text="x" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/zero"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="6dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/seven"
        android:onClick="appendZero"
        android:text="0" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/mod"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="6dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/eight"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/zero"
        android:onClick="modOperation"
        android:text="%" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/division"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="6dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/nine"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/mod"
        android:onClick="divisionOperation"
        android:text="/" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/equal"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="6dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/mul"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/division"
        android:onClick="equalOperation"
        android:text="=" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: @ADM I understand what's the difference but here the behaviour is different. Most close question I saw https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12805091/issue-with-id-vs-id-in-positioning-in-relative-layout but there also in xml, id is used before creating the id object.

Comment: So, i think you already know the reason.

Comment: try to use the `android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/two"` for button one.But your code is not good for production.

Comment: @RishabhRawat I don't want to use + symbol as I already defined the id in previous button.

Comment: Could i post the code for your this app but its totally different from your code

Comment: @ADM  as per my understand if I have defined `android:id="@+id/one"` I can use id:one later part of xml without using + sign. Like for button two I can use `android:layout_toRightOf="@id/one"`

Comment: I already remove '+' but it still work good.

Comment: True that . It will work .. I have tested your layout with the changes you have given and it works . Are you sure you are not missing anything else ?

Comment: @MeosCoder I am running this in Ubuntu and I am facing this issue. My android studio is updated.

Comment: @ADM I copy pasted the same source xml what I wrote in android studio.

Comment: I use Ubuntu and AS 3.1, too! And compileSdkVersion 26

Comment: I do not think AS version has something to do with it and nor the OS your are running on . Rebuild and run the app .

Comment: You can show `onCreate` with `setContentView` snippet?

Comment: I haven't written the onCreate function yet I was doing the Layout part and end up here. Ofcourse there is default onCreate function already defined. `protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }`

Comment: After restarting AS, it started working properly.